# Custom prometheus alert without word in config.yml

Tags: regex, yaml, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

i try to not have all Disk alert from prometheus alert manager so i put this code on config.yml,

my code is:

```
  - match:
      severity: critical
       env:internal
       alertname:'?!.*Disk.*'
    receiver: rocketchat
    continue: true
```

i don't know why that not work, thanks for any help.

Comment: why do you have `?!` at the beginning of your regex?

Comment: isnt that a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851661/prometheus-alertname-multiple-regex